# To Display a signature pad in ant design forms

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, antd

I want to display signature pad in ant design form by which user can sign in form. how can i display that and what libraries i will use to achieve that

I tried with react-signature canvas library but it is not displaying a signature pad in form of antd

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask